# How can I improve numerical stability when propagating a change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, precision

I'm trying to propagate a changed value along a list of numbers.
The changes are rather small, but the values in the list can be large.
This leads to some numerical instability that I want to prevent.

**Example:**

```cs
    public class Polyline
    {
        private List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();

        // For every point in points, contains the total polyline length
        // from the first point up to this point.
        private List<double> distances = new List<double>({0.0});

        [...]

        public void Insert(int index, Vector3 point)
        {
            points.Insert(index, point);

            if (points.Count >= 2)
            {
                double change;

                if (index == 0)
                {
                    // Point gets inserted at the start of the polyline
                    distances.Insert(0, 0f);
                    change = VectorMath.PreciseDistance(points[1], point); 
                }
                else if (index == points.Count - 1)
                {
                    // Point gets inserted at the end of the polyline
                    change = 0.0;
                    var length = VectorMath.PreciseDistance(point, points[index - 1]);
                    var prevLength = distances[distances.Count - 1];
                    distances.Add(prevLength + length);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Point gets added somewhere inside the polyline
                    var prev = points[index - 1];
                    var next = points[index + 1];
                    var prevLength = distances[index - 1];

                    // Get the edge lengths of the resulting triangle (prev, point, next)
                    var l0 = VectorMath.PreciseDistance(point, prev);
                    var l1 = VectorMath.PreciseDistance(next, point);
                    var lOld = distances[index] - prevLength;

                    distances.Insert(index, prevLength + l0);

                    change = l0 + l1 - lOld;
                }

                // Propagate the distance change along subsequent distances
                for (var i = index + 1; i < distances.Count; i++)
                {
                    distances[i] += change;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class VectorMath
    {
        // Calculates the distance as precise as possible
        public static double PreciseDistance(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
        {
            var x = (double) (a.x) - b.x;
            var y = (double) (a.y) - b.y;
            var z = (double) (a.z) - b.z;

            return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        }
    }
```

In this example, I have a polyline class, that stores its points, and also a list of distances.
These distances represent the length of the polyline up to the point at the same index.

When the polyline is long, insertions cause numerical instability.
Especially in later entries, where the total length is large, the imprecission becomes to large.

**Question:**
How can I change the code/system, such that I still have a way to find the total length for a given index, while not having to worry about numerical instability.
Finding that length should be fast, so recalculating it every time it's needed is not feasible.

Assuming that the change value is precise enough.
*Also I want to prevent using doubles or decimals, as performance is a big issue.*

**Background:**
My problem is actually with a polyline class.
If possible, I would like to keep the distances using floating point precission, as the rest of the framework uses floats too.

To get an idea about the instability:
Given 1000 points inserted in random order and a total length of around 5000 units.
The difference of the actual length and the total length stored in the last distance entry is about +-0.2f.

**Note:**
In the original post, I used floats for the distances.
As @derHugo correctly noted, floats have a precision of about 6-9 digits, so the error is to be expected.
However, after changing everything to double (except for Vector3 -> Unity class), the numerical error only decreased by about one digit.
Thus the question remains.

I added the complete source code of Insert, maybe I have a fault there...

Comment: use a [more precise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) value type like e.g. `double` or `decimal`. Then when accessing them you can still shrink it back to a float where needed

Comment: As @derHugo said you should use a more precise type and convert it back to float after your computation. Their is no way to be more precise with float...

Comment: I might not have stated it clearly enough, but I want to prevent that. Once because the rest of the framework uses floats, but also because of performance reasons. And yes, I'm going to use this code in performance critical code. I'm gona update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: well let's face it as you can see in the link `float` has a precision of `6-9` digits. `5000` already occupies 4 digits. So 2-5 left behind the comma. Multiplied by 1000 entries takes again 3 digits away leaving you with a precision of something between 1 and 0.01

Comment: Still, if I calculate the distance from scratch, using a float, then I get a big difference to the propagated distance. I want to minimize this distance.

Comment: I just realized that my previous comment didn't make much sense as answer to your reply. Your reasoning with the digits makes sense. I'll try it with doubles.

Comment: @derHugo: I changed everything to doubles (except for Vector3, thats a Unity3d class). The numerical error decreased by about one digit, way less than I thought it would. So there's another problem except for the digit precision of floats. Can you take a second look and tell what I'm doing wrong? I updated the question with more source code.